# tf.keras mean_squared_error strange return when data length > batch size

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function, mean-square-error

MSE as a loss function in a sequential model, does not work properly when data length > batch size.

Let's start with data length < 32.
In this case it works fine, next we'll do the same with 3 more values in data.

Firstly we get our data, then we calculate MSE, then we run one epoch of our simple sequential model with loss function = MSE. We'll see here that the loss function return is right.

In a second step, we'll do it again with 3 more values. MSE returned by the model will be different.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
# tf version : 2.2.0

mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

xs = np.arange(-10,20,1,dtype="float32")
# from -10. to 19.

def hw_function(x) : 
    return (2 * x) - 1

ys = np.apply_along_axis(hw_function, 0, xs)
# from -21. to 37.
# len(ys) = 30

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
# model.weights

# e.g random weights ) bias = 0
# [<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1.6994196]], dtype=float32)>,
# <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]

xxs=xs*model.weights[0][0][0]

mse(xxs, ys).numpy()
# MSE = 6.8929496 

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=1)

# 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 6.8929
# <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9ab05130f0>
# we get MSE = 6.8929 that's perfect
```

We do exactly the same, but in place of 30 values, we have 33 values.
Of course weights are random values

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
# tf version : 2.2.0

mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

xs = np.arange(-10,20,1,dtype="float32")
# from -10. to 22.
def hw_function(x) : 
    return (2 * x) - 1
ys = np.apply_along_axis(hw_function, 0, xs)
# from -21. to 43.
# len(ys) = 33

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
# model.weights
# e.g
# [<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[-1.1775365]], dtype=float32)>,
# <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]

# bias = 0 
xxs=xs*model.weights[0][0][0]

mse(xxs, ys).numpy()
# we get 1241.7897

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=1)

# 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1249.6738
# <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9ab05130f0>
# we get MSE = 1249.6738 it's an error
```

Here is my question. 
Why, when the data length is > batch size, we don't get the right value by MSE as a loss function in a sequential model?

If in place of MSE I use MAE it works fine, value returned by the model is correct when data>batch size.

It's in relation with the batch size. When data length < 32 it works fine (always) but when it's > 32, it fails every time for MSE

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I exactly understand what you are trying to do here, but your problem is related to the fact that, by default, in `model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=1)`, `batch_size` parameter is equal to `32`.

This is why your code fails, if you set it to `64` and increase your `ys` dimension in the experiment you are doing, your problem should be solved.

Comment: I agree, if I replace 32 by 64 it works because it's like being in the 1st case of my example but what does it mean? if my data size is x my batch size needs to be >x when there is a small size of data?